# ImmutableJS - Update only one key-value in Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, immutable.js

I have the following Immutable state initially in my reducer:

```
const firstState = Map({ "1": {title: "Hello 1", content: "Content 1"}, "2" : {title: "Hello 2", content: "Content 2"} });
```

Now, in my reducer, when a EDIT_POST action comes in I would like to change some of these fields, if they were changed by the user. So say the user edited the title field (of post no. 1) only. Then I would like to have a new state with the title field changed, but the content field intact.

However, I don't know how to do this.

I have tried a few things, e.g. these two things (at separate times):

```
case 'EDIT_POST': {
        var obj = state.get(action.id);

        //let newState = state.setIn(['1','title'], 'New Title');
        //let newState = state.set("1", {title: "New Title"});
        return newState;
      }
```

The first thing does not work at all, the second thing does away with all other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setIn` isn't working becuase you're mixing plain Javascript objects and immutable.js objects. immutable.js assumes that the entire object is composed of immutable.js objects.

Your map:

```
const firstState = Map({ "1": {title: "Hello 1", content: "Content 1"}, "2" : {title: "Hello 2", content: "Content 2"} });
```

should look more like this:

```
const firstState = Map({
    "1": Map({ title: "Hello 1", content: "Content 1" }),
    "2": Map({ title: "Hello 2", content: "Content 2" })
});
```

The nested objects have to be instance of Map or another immutable type, then `setIn` will work.

If you have a plain JS object and want to convert it to an immutable object you can use `Immutable.fromJS(someObject)`

Comment: this is amazing, exactly the answer I needed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need `setIn()` method. Try this.

```
case 'EDIT_POST': {
    var obj = state.get(action.id);

    let newState = state.setIn(['1','title'], 'New Title');
    return newState;
}
```

Comment: this is what I tried already. Sorry there is a typo above, which I will correct now, but I did try the `setIn` method.

Comment: @GeorgeWelder When you create the immutable state, have you tried using `Immutable.fromJS()` instead of `Map()` ?

Comment: no, will try that now. will this create a Map though?

Comment: From the docs I get 'fromJS() Deeply converts plain JS objects and arrays to Immutable Maps and Lists.'